# Has $e^x = ax^2$ a general solution for all $x$?

Tags: exponential-function, lambert-w

I was fiddling around with some math and stumbled upon $\exp(x) = a x^2$, finding myself unable to find a solution. Does it even have a general solution $a$ for all $x$? Some googling brought me to the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), which I've never encountered before.

Comment: Did you mean a general solution $x$ for all $a$ ? Otherwise the solution is $a = exp(x)/x^2$ if $ x \neq 0$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lambert W solution like this:
$$
e^x=ax^2
\\
e^{x/2} = \sqrt{a} \;x
\\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}=x\;e^{-x/2}
\\
-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{a}}=-\frac{x}{2}\;e^{-x/2}
\\
W\left(-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{a}}\right) = -\frac{x}{2}
\\
-2W\left(-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{a}}\right)=x
$$
... and, as Robert notes, also solutions for the other square-root.

Answer (score 4):

Which do you want to solve for, $a$ or $x$?  Solving for $a$ is easy:
$a = x^{-2} \exp(x)$ (assuming of course $x \ne 0$).  Solving for $x$ is where you need Lambert:
$$ x = - 2 W(\pm 1/(2 \sqrt{a}))$$
where $W$ is a branch of the Lambert W function.
If $a$ is real and you're looking for real solutions, there are none if $a \le 0$,  one ($-2 W(+1/\sqrt{a})$) if $0 < a < e^2/4$, 
two if $a = e^2/4$, three if $a > e^2/4$.

Comment: I meant for a constant a, so yeah, this means solving for x. I'll read myself into that Lambert function

Comment: I would personally use $W_k$ to denote branches.